# How do you call someone who gives classes but is not actually a teacher?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

How would you call someone who gives classes to students despite not having a degree in teaching nor it being their main occupation ?

For example, a lot of "teachers" I had in college were actually professionals in the field they were teaching, who would only do this for 2 or 4 hours a week in addition to their main job.

In France I have heard the term "Chargé d'enseignement", which litterally means "In charge of teaching".

Is there a similar word or expression in English ? Or would you just call them teachers ?

Comment: Guest lecturer?

Comment: Are you looking for British or American English?

Comment: In InE, it's 'external faculty'. I'm one of them! ^-^ We don't have degree in *teaching*, but we have experience and expertise in the subject

Comment: Maybe honorary teacher, lecturer, or professor.  Also he may be a called a guest lecturer.

Comment: @Khan - I would say a _guest lecturer_ refers to someone who is asked to give one lecture or two lectures in a class. This person would not be the normal instructor, and may not even get paid for the appearance.

Comment: J.R. Then you are right ; it's adjunct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule, they aren't called *teachers* at or above the university level, they are called *instructors* or *professors*. The term you are looking for is ***adjunct***, and you could call this person an *adjunct professor,* or an *adjunct faculty member.*

NOAD defines the word like this:

> **adjunct** (*adj.*) (of an academic post) attached to the staff of a college in a temporary or assistant capacity : *an adjunct professor of entomology*. [as n.] *both adjuncts and tenured professors tend to inflate grades*.

Comment: I did not know about 'teacher' only being used below university level. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: I'd be wary of using "professor" as a catch-all term here, as it's a specific academic title that not everyone giving a lecture will have (someone with a postdoctoral position giving a lecture course - which is very common - is not a "professor"). "Lecturer" is much broader.

Comment: @JezW - I concur with your wariness, but the boundary lines are muddled. It depends on a lot of things: Who is looking for this term, and why do they want to use it? Are we looking for a term that a university will use to clarify academic rank? Or trying to explain what the students should call these individuals in the classroom? (Also, my answer doesn't say that _professor_ is the right term to use – it says that "teacher" is the wrong term. "Lecturer" is a good addition to my answer, though; thanks for commenting.)

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use the word "instructor" in this case. The New Oxford American Dictionary has the definition "A person who teaches something:" which I think covers your use, too.

Answer (score 0):

An effective adjunct professor is someone who is:

- A clear communicator
- Able to teach with ample real-world experience
- Able to show confidence teaching and presenting to a class
- Technologically savvy: can utilize email, different online learning
  systems and other ways to communicate with students
- Passionate about specific academic fields and education in general.

I am an adjunct nursing professor with over 20 years ecperience. I have a ADN,BSN, MSN. I feel that I deserve to be called a professor.